What locations does Neovim look to autocomplete?
I have a question about autocompletion in Neovim. I installed PEGTL (a C++ lib for developing parsers) and when I wrote code in Neovim, it didn't show suggestions for autocompletion when I pressed Ctrl-x-o. Then I moved the directory that contained the PEGTL lib to /usr/local/include, and Neovim started to show suggestions. Now I want to do the same for Django, because Neovim is not showing suggestions for it. My questions is: What locations does Neovim look to autocomplete?
I tried to search something related to this question in the source code for neovim, but did not find anything.

Start your research with :help 'omnifunc' and follow the hotlinks to other relevant help topics.
